# Sailsjs: Difference between `req.body` and `req.params.all()`

Tags: express, sails.js

What is the difference between `req.body` and `req.params.all()` when used in a sails controller?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`req.body` is whatever was parsed out of the request body, for example the payload in a `POST` request.  `req.params.all()` gives you the collection of parameters culled from (in order of precedence):

- the route (e.g. the `id` in `/post/:id`).
- the request body
- the query string

Comment: Is this decreasing order of precedence or increasing?  If 'id' is set in the route and the query string, which one is returned?

Comment: It's in increasing order; query string params override body params, which override route params.

Comment: Note than in the upcoming Sails 1.0 this order is reversed to fall in line with how it is in Express by default: route params override body params, and body params override query string.

Answer (score 0):

A problem I've noticed while using req.params in a PUT request is:

`PUT /route/1
{
id:2,
param:2
}`

the req.body.id overwrites the one from req.params.all().id and the req.params.all().id becomes 2.

Seems to be fixed in Sails v1.